# Uploading development phase application on TestFlight for testing gives alert email from Apple

Tags: ios, build, testflight

I have received below email from Apple. I am not able to understand why did I receive it. Shouldn't development phase applications be uploaded on TestFlight for internal testing? I haven't submitted app for beta review.

> From:  Apple
>   Date: 11/5/15, 7:47 PM
>   2. - FUNCTIONALITY
>
> **2.9 Details**
>
> Your app appears to be a pre-release, test, or trial version with a limited feature set. Apps that are created for demonstration or trial purposes are not appropriate for the App Store.
>
> **Next Steps**
>
> Please revise your app to complete, remove, or fully configure any partially implemented feature(s).
>
> **Resources**
>
> If you would like to conduct a beta trial for your app, you may wish to review the https://developer.apple.com/app-store/testflight/“>TestFlight Beta Testing Guide.

Comment: It looks like you submitted your incomplete app for review. Don't do that. You would not get this rejection from a TestFlight beta review submission.

Comment: @Paulw11 I didn't submit it for any review. Not even beta review.

Comment: Apple doesn't review apps that aren't submitted for review and they don't reject apps they haven't reviewed.  You or someone else in your team submitted the app for review. In iTunesConnect go to "My Apps->App Name->Activity->App Store Versions" to check the submission/review actions

Answer (score 0):

In general when you upload your app to TestFlight it runs the Apple App Store checks and gives you warnings against them. Since Apple bought TestFlight it has become more of a testing platform for the App Store. If you want to get Ad Hoc builds out to a limited set of users when the app isn't fully completed yet I would suggest using something like HockeyApp:
https://www.hockeyapp.net

Comment: I couldn't find anything similar mentioned in TestFlight or on iTunes guidelines. Can you support your answer with some reference ?